# How to serve more than one site in azure webapp with different domain

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

Is the following possible if so how?

I have a website setup with azure webapp lets say its www.mysite1.com it sits in folder site/mysite1

I want to also have www.mynewsite.com its going to sit in folder site/mynewsite is there way to setup domain for this second site in webapp settings?  I can see how to setup site with virtual directory then setup sub domain however in this case I want different domain.

The 2nd site is very small and I want to try and avoid creating a new webapp app for it if possible.

Comment: The 2nd app service doesn't cost you any extra if on the same plan so why not make another app service

Comment: Cool this is what I have done and all working fine.

Answer (score 0):

In configuration -> Path mappings there is a setting for virtual applications:

[image: path mappings]

However I don't think they can have separate domains, unless you do some sort of IIS Rewrite rewrite rule to rewrite requests for the 2nd domain, in that instance though you'd probably be better off setting up a 2nd app service on the same plan